# Do I have to use bodyParser in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, body-parser

I was using bodyParser.json() as a middleware with express and I recently replaced it by this code :

```
//gets any json object and put them in req.body
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let lang = req.acceptsLanguages()[0];
    const decoder = new StringDecoder('UTF-8');
    req.on('data', function(data) {
        try {
            req.body = JSON.parse(decoder.write(data));
            next()
        } catch (ex) {

            res.status(400).send(translator(lang, 'entry.error.input.malformed'));
        }
    });
});
```

Do I have to use bodyParser and add the library to my project ? or my custom code is enough to parse and inject raw data as Json object in req??

Answer (score 1):

Your custom middleware doesn't quite seem right, i would use

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  let lang = req.acceptsLanguages()[0];
  let data = '';
  req.on('data', chunk => data += chunk);
  req.on('end', () => {
    try {
        req.body = JSON.parse(data);
        next()
    } catch (ex) {
      res.status(400).send(translator(lang, 'entry.error.input.malformed'));
    }
  });
});
```

And yes this is enough, if you expect, all the requests coming into the server to be of JSON type. bodyparser basically does the same, except that, it handles a lot other cases

Comment: `chunk => data += chunk`, `String addition` in some encoding which is not use 1 byte to store 1 character will garbled,  using `Buffer` instead.

Comment: Like that ? 
` let data = [];

    req.on('data', chunk => data.push(chunk));`